# Ransack won't sort counted column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have a problem with my sorting.

Ransack works fine when sorting the `id` and `mac` columns, but it won't work on the `frequency` column. In the logs nothing appeared when I clicked on `frequency`.

Model:

```
scope :with_frequency, -> {
select('devices.*,tr.times AS frequency').
joins('join (SELECT device_id,count(device_id) AS times FROM timed_requests tr GROUP BY device_id) AS tr ON tr.device_id = devices.id')}
```

Controller:

```
def index
@search = Device.with_frequency.search(params[:q])
@search.sorts = 'frequency desc' if @search.sorts.empty?
@devices = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
end
```

View:

```
%th= sort_link @search, :id, "ID"
%th= sort_link @search, :mac, "MAC-Addresse"
%th= sort_link @search, :frequency, "Frequency"
```

Logs (first click on Frequency than ID):

```
Parameters: {"page"=>"1", "q"=>{"s"=>"frequency desc"}}
Device Load (39.8ms)  SELECT devices.*,tr.times AS frequency FROM "devices" join (SELECT     device_id,count(device_id) AS times FROM timed_requests tr GROUP BY device_id) AS tr ON        tr.device_id = devices.id LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Parameters: {"page"=>"1", "q"=>{"s"=>"id asc"}}
Device Load (61.3ms)  SELECT devices.*,tr.times AS frequency FROM "devices" join (SELECT device_id,count(device_id) AS times FROM timed_requests tr GROUP BY device_id) AS tr ON tr.device_id = devices.id ORDER BY "devices"."id" ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the problem is that `Device` does not have `frequency` column. Try to include column in join statement like `GROUP BY device_id ORDER BY times`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is the problem but i dont know a solution. The adding from `GROUP BY device_id ORDER BY times` dont work

Comment: Why your scope name is `with_frequency` but you call `frequency` in controller instead?

Comment: This is a copy&paste error. I call in the controller the `with_frequency` scope

Comment: I have the exact same issue. @ThreeFingerMark Did you find a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @lou No, this dont work with Ransack. I think it lies on the join. I made this SQL Statement without Ransack